# how to show right side of image

Tags: html, css

I want to display only right side of image

How I can do that?

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2942699.jpg">
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to have only half of the containing element covered in an image? And which part of that image, bearing in mind that the aspect ratios of the container and the image may be different.

Comment: I nothing said about half part i only say about right side of image. If you mit it takes half of screen size or no - it depends on users monitor width

Comment: Anyway I answer on my question and I'm sure that can be useful for others

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: right;
```

Also it can be in percentage

```
background-position: 60%;
```